# .Net Parameter Attribute to make named/optional Parameter visible only internally/private?

Tags: .net, syntactic-sugar, named-parameters

Out of curiosity, is there a way to write a method e.g. like this:

```
public static MyType Parse(string stringRepresentation, [Internal] bool throwException = true)
{
// parsing logic here that conditionally throws an exception or returns null ...
}

public static MyType TryParse(string stringRepresentation)
{
return this.Parse(stringRepresentation, true);
}
```

I want to cut down code redundancies internally, but remain compliant to e.g. BCL method signatures for (Try)Parse() but if the c# compiler could in this case generate a second, internal method that would be nice.

Is that already somehow possible? Couldn't find anything so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not aware that you can, but wouldn't this give you the same result?

```
public MyType Parse(string stringRepresentation)
{
    return this.Parse(stringRepresentation, true);
}

internal MyType Parse(string stringRepresentation, bool throwException = true)
{
    // parsing logic here that conditionally throws an exception or returns null ...
}
```

Comment: Yep that's of course what I'm doing, was just wondering whether I could cut out the first/public boilerplate method there and put it in one.

Comment: @JörgB optional parameters can make versioning (e.g. adding more overloads later) harder, so there is already good reason to stick with plain overloads in a public/protected interface.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a bit late answer, but it might be of help to somebody else.

You can decoreate your attribute class with **AttributeTargets.Parameter** ([here is the msdn link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177223.aspx)) which is exactly what you are looking for.

A sample attribute:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Parameter, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class InternalAttribute : Attribute
{
    // attribute code goes here
}
```

Usage of the attribute:

```
public void Foo([Internal] type_of_parameter parameter_name)
{
      //code
}
```